# Calculating Damage

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I could really use some help with someone who knows what all this actuality means. I'm trying to figure out what my damage  would be with a regular attack and power attack and magical weapons. I have a MC magical greatsword with +1 weapon bonus, but what is that  +1 to? To hit? To the dice roll (3d6 on a 2d6 base)? Just a straight bonus damage(2d6+1)? And the second part is using that to power attack, with my character level 6 i have enough BAB for the +2 bonus to be a +4 bonus on melee damage rolls, but what does a bonus on a melee damage rolls mean in this context? (And yes i know the bonus would be +6 with a greatsword power attack). I would really appreciate someone who actually understands this word jumble to explain it for me. Thanks :P

Comment: Welcome to the site and, presumably, the hobby! Take the [tour]. There *is* a lot of jargon in *Pathfinder* in particular, and getting a handle on it all can be a daunting task; you have my respect and sympathy for attempting this endeavor. I am curious what an *MC magical greatsword* is, but beyond clarifying that, I'm certain answers will be able to help. Thank you for participating and have fun.

Answer (score 5):

damage = weapon base damage + (Strength modifier + power attack bonus)*number_of_hands_modifier + magic weapon bonus

- weapon base damage: something like 2d6, 1d8, 1d10... It's written in the weapon's description.
- Strength modifier: (Strength score - 10)/2 (rounded down)
- power attack bonus: +2, increases by +2 for each +4 BAB (eg for a character with BAB+7 it would be +4)
- number_of_hands_bonus: 1 if the weapon is one-handed, 1.5 if it's two-handed, 0.5 if it's wielded in your off hand
- magic weapon bonus: a +X weapon gives you +X to your damages (this bonus also apply on the attack roll)

On top of that some special effects can add other damages, like sneak attack dice, weapon with the bane property or a Paladin smiting evil.

Example: Bob the goblin has a strength of 9 and a +3 one-handed scimitar. He's a lvl 1 Warrior and used the feat Power Attack.

If he hits, he will inflict 1d8(scimitar)-1(Strength modifier)+2(Power attack)+3(magical weapon) damages: he rolls 1d8 and add +4 to the result.

Comment: Ahh, so the +X weapon bonus and adding to the melee damage rolls means it's just a modifier that adds additional damage flat. Thanks!

Comment: @Meek: yes, and it also adds up to your attack roll and can help bypassing DR, but that's an other story.

Comment: @Meek magical weapons add their 'Enhancement Bonus' as a flat + to both chance 'to hit' and damage. That wasn't necessarily part of the question, so it wasn't covered in this answer (but is good to know)